# Strange NativeScript/Angular2 issue, app looks for templates in the wrong location

Tags: angular, webpack, barcode-scanner, nativescript

I have a very basic Nativescript/Angular2 barcode scanner app where I just started to implement routing...

I have a Home component located at `app/pages/home/home.component.ts` and the home component's template is located in the same folder `app/home/home.component.html`  When I build the app everyting seems to work fine untill the app gets deployed on a genyMotion emulator.  I then get the below error.

It seems like it's looking for the home component's template under `app/home.component.html` for some reason?  Any idea why this would happen?  I checked and the import statements of all modules that reference the home component is correct.  Any idea how I can go about figuring out what's happening here?

#### My error:

```js
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {org.nativescript.barcodescanner/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreateView failed

Error: File /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/home.component.html does not exist. Resolved from: home.component.html.
File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js, line: 22, column: 12
```

#### StackTrace:

```js
    Frame: function:'FileSystemResourceLoader.get', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/resource-loader.js', line: 22, column: 19
    Frame: function:'DirectiveNormalizer._fetch', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js', line: 13661, column: 45
    Frame: function:'DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modul
```

#### my home.component.ts:

```js
import { Component,} from '@angular/core';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html' 
})
export class HomeComponent {

  constructor(private restService: RestService, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {

}
    

}
```

#### my app.routing.ts: (lots commented out of this file as i'm busy converting a web app to mobile and still in the process of adding all components...)

```js
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
//import { ProductComponent } from './components/product/product.component';
//import { StockTransactionComponent } from './Components/stock-transaction/stock-transaction.component';
//import { CheckBarcodesComponent } from './Components/check-barcodes/check-barcodes.component';
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
//import { SettingsComponent } from './Components/settings/settings.component';

export const routes = [
    //{path: "settings", component: SettingsComponent },
//  {path: "checkBarcodes", component: CheckBarcodesComponent },    
    {path: "", component: HomeComponent}
];

export const navigatableComponents = [
HomeComponent
];
```

#### my app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule, ValueProvider } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from 'nativescript-angular/router'
import { NativeScriptHttpModule } from 'nativescript-angular/http';


import { BarcodeScanner } from "nativescript-barcodescanner";

import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
import { routes, navigatableComponents } from './app.routing';
@NgModule({
    imports : [
    NativeScriptModule,     
    NativeScriptFormsModule ,
    NativeScriptHttpModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule,
    NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations : [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ...navigatableComponents
    ],
    providers : [
    RestService,
    BarcodeScanner],
    bootstrap : [AppComponent]      
})
export class AppModule {}

my app.component.ts:


import { Component } from "@angular/core";



@Component({
    selector: "main",
    template : "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Comment: Hope you understand what's happening with relative urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `templateUrl` to `template` and use inline html code.

```
templateUrl: './home.component.html' => template: `<!-- contents of ./home.component.html -->`
```

---

The url that is used in the `templateUrl` *is not* component-relative. You should read more about [componet-relative urls](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html) and how to load them with webpack from the cookbook.

> By default, we must specify the full path back to the application
>   root. We call this an absolute path because it is absolute with
>   respect to the application root.
>
> There are two problems with an absolute path:
>
> ```
> We have to remember the full path back to the application root.
>
> We have to update the URL when we move the component around in the application files structure.
> ```
>
> It would be much easier to write and maintain our application
>   components if we could specify template and style locations relative
>   to their component class file.

Component-relative paths *are not* default in Angular. And you should read why.

> [Appendix: why component-relative is not the default](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#why-default)
>
> Webpack users may prefer an [alternative approach](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#webpack).

---

### Summary:

You can try to use *component-relative* or *absolute* urls in the `templateUrl` attribute, but the *inline* solution is simple and easy. 
You can also read [Creating Your First Angular 2 Components](https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-your-first-angular-2-components) tutorial for approaching with your component templates.

Comment: Why can't I use a templateUrl?

Comment: Url is no longer valid when you deployed.

Comment: This isn't a web app though?  Also the web app which i'm busy converting to this Nativescript app uses webPack and there the relative URL's seem to work fine...?

Comment: no it's not true until you use specific loader with webpack

Comment: @user2094257 Did you try this solution?

Comment: Yes it worked but I want to use separate template files so it turns out adding the absolute path instead of the relative path worked...  Thanks for taking a look:)

Comment: The absolute url works but you didn't use absolute url.

Comment: i'll accept your answer, but can you please add this explanation in there to make it a bit more clear/useful to future viewers?  Just add that the absolute URL must be used when using separate template files...  Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried adding `moduleId` to the `@Component` definition? I've read it breaks Webpack compatibility but I dunno if that matters to you:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: "home.component.html",
  // ..
})
```

Then just have `home.component.html` in the same folder as this component.

Comment: Hey @Eddy Verbruggen so @Component({ moduleId: AppModule, templateUrl: './home.html'?  Btw loving your barcodescanner plugin:)

Comment: Haha, thanks! The syntax is exactly as the example (don't replace module.id by a value) and don't prefix the template with "./".

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like NativeScript needs the absolute path when using a separate Template this worked for me (pages/home/home.component.ts):

templateUrl: './pages/home/home.component.html';